# Get nearest point from another one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a point, called `i`, which is

```
{
  x: 10000,
  y: 10000
}
```

And I have some other points, in an array, something like:

```
[{
  x: 35,
  y: 10001
}, {
  x: 2478,
  y: 38
}, ...]
```

My question is, how to, in JavaScript, get the nearest point from `i`?
Thanks!

Comment: can edit your question with some examples and the outputs that you expect. Also provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and how it's not working? People on StackOverflow will be much more likely to help if you do this.

Comment: How about a loop?

Answer (score 8):

You could reduce the array by taking the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space) of the points and take the point with the smaller distance.

```js
function distance(p) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x - p.x, 2) + Math.pow(point.y - p.y, 2))
}

var point = { x: 10000, y: 10000 },
    points = [{ x: 35, y: 10001 }, { x: 2478, y: 38 }],
    closest = points.reduce((a, b) => distance(a) < distance(b) ? a : b);

console.log(closest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **pythagoras theorem** to compute the distance from your point to each point inside the array.

```js
var myPoint = {
  x: 10000,
  y: 10000
};
var points = [{
  x: 35,
  y: 10001
}, {
  x: 2478,
  y: 38
}];

var minDistance = 10000000;
var closestPoint;
for (var a = 0; a < points.length; a++) {
  distance = Math.sqrt((myPoint.x - points[a].x) * (myPoint.x - points[a].x) + (myPoint.y - points[a].y) * (myPoint.y - points[a].y));
  if (distance < minDistance) {
    minDistance = distance;
    closestPoint = points[a];
  }
}
console.log("The closest point: x="+closestPoint.x+", y="+closestPoint.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some basic geometry to create a function get the absolute distance b/w two points and then loop through array and find the object which gives minimum distance.

```js
let p = {
  x: 10000,
  y: 10000
}

let arr = [{
  x: 35,
  y: 10001
}, {
  x: 2478,
  y: 38
}]

function getDiaDist(point){
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x,2) + Math.pow(point.y,2))
}

function getDistance(p1,p2){
  return getDiaDist({x:p1.x - p2.x, y:p1.y - p2.y})
}

function getNearestPoint(arr,point){
  let min = Infinity;
  let result = arr[0]
  arr.forEach(a => {
    let dist = getDistance(a,point);
    if(dist > min){
      min = dist
      result = a;
    }
  })
  return result;
}



console.log(getNearestPoint(arr,p))
```